# Select distinct a row in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, distinct

I have a database where I have two columns like you can see above.
Note that the second line is equal to the first but the third is different as you can see

```
number_chip| Date_of_Scanned_chip
   345             2016-12-12
   345             2016-12-12
   345             2017-1-03
```

The DISTINCT on the column (number_chip) eliminates all the chips and gives me only one

```
   number_chip| Date_of_Scanned_chip
       345             2016-12-12
```

But I want something that gives me this. Please help :)

```
number_chip| Date_of_Scanned_chip
       345             2016-12-12
       345             2017-1-03 //Eliminates the second line
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to all the columns, not any particular one. Please provide a [MCVE] to demonstrate your  problem.

Comment: Yes but I can have diferent number_chips with the same Date_of_Scanned_chip. As obvious I dont want to do a distinct in that date because in the table there are repetitive dates

Comment: You need to post the actual query, because `SELECT DISTINCT` should have done what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The DISTINCT on the column (number_chip) eliminates all the chips and
>   gives me only one

I cannot imagine what you mean by this.  A simple query:

```
select distinct number_chip, Date_of_Scanned_chip
from t;
```

seems to do exactly what you want to do.  `select distinct` is a statement in SQL.  There is no `distinct` in SQL that operates on one column.

Comment: I must have repetitive dates :/ because different chips can have equal scan_dates

Comment: @Jose This will do that. It only removes duplicates where both columns are the same.

Answer (score -1):

GROUP BY number_chip, Date_of_Scanned_chip;

Comment: When the columns in `GROUP BY` are the same as all the columns you're selecting, it's the same as `SELECT DISTINCT`.